# Insert GEO location into input HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to locate City and Country and insert the info inside  tag field as value.
Tried several options and none worked for me, the original code successfully inserted the info into  element but this is not what I need.

I have tried to give id name to my input tags and insert the text inside like this:  $('#country').value(fulladd[count-1]);
but it didn't worked, the output is

```
<input type="text" tabindex="3" name="city">Whatever</input>
```

```js
function locate() {

  var location = document.getElementById("location");
  var apiKey = 'f536d4c3330c0a1391370d1443cee848';
  var url = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/';

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

  function success(position) {
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;


     $.getJSON("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latitude + "," + longitude + "&language=en", function(data) {
  var fulladd = data.results[0].formatted_address.split(",");
  var count= fulladd.length;
      $('#country').text(fulladd[count-1]);
      $('#city').text(fulladd[count-2]);
    });
  }

  function error() {
    location.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  }
$('#country').text('Locating...')
}

locate();
```

```html
<html lang="en">

   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <title> Locating </title>
   </head>

   <body>
<form id="form1">
     <div class="registration_form">
      <section id="location">
            <div id="country">
                <label>
                Country<br><input type="text" tabindex="3" value="0" 
                             name="country" >
                </label>
            </div>
            <div id="city">
                <label>
                City<br><input type="text" tabindex="3" name="city">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
       </section>
    </div>
</form>
   
   </body>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: You have a live demo in your question that is reporting errors such as *Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined*, maybe you should address them?

Comment: @Quentin I edited the code,unfortunately here its not working but when I run it locally it works, but not as I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had 2 problems:

1. $('#country').text('Locating...') is set your div to plain text and then you can't treat it like input field, so you have to delete it.
2. you try to get the wrong element tag. Try get the input specifically and not his container tag.

fixed HTML :

```
<div id="country">
  <label>Country</label>
  <input id="countryInput" type="text" tabindex="3" name="country">
</div>
<div id="city">
  <label>City</label>
  <input id="cityInput" type="text" tabindex="3" name="city">
</div>
```

and fixed JS:

```
function locate() {

  var location = document.getElementById("location");
  var apiKey = 'f536d4c3330c0a1391370d1443cee848';
  var url = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/';

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

  function success(position) {
      latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      longitude = position.coords.longitude;

      $.getJSON("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latitude + "," + longitude + "&language=en", function(data) {
          var fulladd = data.results[0].formatted_address.split(",");
          var count= fulladd.length;

          $('#countryInput').val(fulladd[count-1]);
          $('#cityInput').val(fulladd[count-2]);
      });
  }

  function error() {
      location.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  }
}
```